# How to pipe cmdline output of program to run multiple times and halt when a keyword appears?

Tags: shell

Say I want to run a C program 1000 times, and this program is basically a test script that tests the functionality of a simple kernel I have written. It outputs a "SUCCESS" every time it fails. Because of various race conditions that are hard to track down, we often have to run the test manually literally a few hundred times before it fails. I have tried searching the net in vain for perl scripts or bash scripts that can help us run this command:

```
pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu -j 2 --filesys-size=2 -p tests/vm/page-parallel -a page-parallel -p tests/vm/child-linear -a child-linear --swap-size=4 -- -q -f run page-parallel < /dev/null
```

and pipe the command to something to check for a keyword so it can halt/continue if that keyword appears.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can just run it in a while loop:

```
while true; do
if "pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu -j 2 --filesys-size=2 -p tests/vm/page-parallel -a page-parallel -p tests/vm/child-linear -a child-linear --swap-size=4 -- -q -f run page-parallel < /dev/null" | grep -c KEYWORD; then 
break
fi
done
```

I'm not 100% sure about the quoting you'd need around the command, obviously I can't run your specific command. It may not need the "" around it.

`grep -c` counts the matches, if 0 then the KEYWORD was not found so it runs the loop again. If > 0 then the KEYWORD was found and the loop breaks out.

Comment: Thank you! I the quoting around the command is not required for me. This command worked perfectly for me:
                  
while true; do
if pintos -v -k -T 60 --qemu -j 2 --filesys-size=2 -p tests/vm/page-parallel -a page-parallel -p tests/vm/child-linear -a child-linear --swap-size=4 -- -q -f run page-parallel | grep -c "exit(-1)"; then 
break
fi
done